# Annotation Processor throws NullPointerException in init

Tags: java, annotations

I'm trying to write an annotation processor, but it seems that the `init` method is always being passed a null `ProcessingEnvironment`. I have no experience with annotation processors, but this seems like incorrect behavior. The following is the code:

```
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("*")
public class DocAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnvironment) {
        super.init(processingEnvironment);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage( javax.tools.Diagnostic.Kind.WARNING,"IT WORKS");
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the stack trace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:3.3.2:process (process) on project flowBot: Error executing: java.lang.NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:3.3.2:process (process) on project flowBot: Error executing
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error executing
    at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.execute(AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:429)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:553)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.executeWithExceptionsHandled(AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:766)
    at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.execute(AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:421)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at util.flowAnnotations.DocAnnotationProcessor.init(DocAnnotationProcessor.java:17)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:500)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:597)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:690)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    ... 27 more
```

It seems to me that this should be the minimum working annotation processor. What's going wrong?

Comment: which version of JDK are you using?

Comment: Also, could you post your project on Github?

Comment: What code exactly was on DocAnnotationProcessor.java:17 when you've seen this exception?

Comment: I can't post the project on Github, as it's company code. DocAnnotationProcessor.java:17 was the call to `super`. I'm using JDK 1.8. The important piece of information I didn't mention was that this is a mixed Scala/Java project and this was aimed at Scala classes. I'm learning that that doesn't work. Interestingly, the NPE goes away if I rewrite the processor in Scala, but it will only run on Java code (I guess that makes sense)

Comment: I would take down the question, but there's already a bounty on it'

Comment: Also, FWIW, I think the annotation processor is going away.  I can't recall where I read that, but think I did see it just recently.  Someone else will know for sure.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant part of your pom?  Just adapted your code in some old project that i have and it worked well.  And why are you overriding the `init` method?

Answer (score 0):

Some bit of research to add to this thread:

A [likely bug](https://github.com/bsorrentino/maven-annotation-plugin/issues/66) with source and target -1.8 was fixed in the `3.3.1` release according to the tracker. The [`MojoExecutionException`](https://github.com/bsorrentino/maven-annotation-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bsc/maven/plugin/processor/AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java#L429) is thrown by the plugin during processing when there is a failure while compiling the sources you've provided.

---

A search of `util.flowAnnotations.DocAnnotationProcessor` over the [plugin repository](https://github.com/bsorrentino/maven-annotation-plugin/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=util.flowAnnotations.DocAnnotationProcessor&type=) couldn't lead me to any results and then I read the [comment by you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328601/annotation-processor-throws-nullpointerexception-in-init#comment79810463_46328601) which states that you are using a mix of [scala](/questions/tagged/scala)/[java](/questions/tagged/java) and processing the scala classes. For which, you can use your `CustomProcessor` which could be a similar implementation overriding the [`BaseAbstractProcessor`](https://github.com/bsorrentino/maven-annotation-plugin/blob/master/utils/src/main/java/org/bsc/processor/BaseAbstractProcessor.java) class and then processing the scala code as [`AnnotationProcessorCompiler`](https://github.com/bsorrentino/maven-annotation-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bsc/maven/plugin/processor/AnnotationProcessorCompiler.java) does for java currently.

It would be good to know, that there are already existing stacks like [retronym/annotation-processor](https://github.com/retronym/annotation-processor) that does the same as of today as visible in their [sample processor.](https://github.com/retronym/annotation-processor/blob/master/proc/src/main/java/sample/AnnotationProcessor.java)

---

On contradictory note to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328601/annotation-processor-throws-nullpointerexception-in-init#comment79896631_46328601), I could find the plugin making some progress to be [compatible with Java9.](https://github.com/bsorrentino/maven-annotation-plugin/issues/69)